# Is there a way to check .chars is empty or not while my variable is int type?

Tags: java, javafx

I am creating desktop application and I am facing a problem that I can't find a way to check if my is variable empty or not. In field user must enter a number. OK - if he enters number so how to check that he really entered it and did not left empty field? Should I try to convert my variable amziusCheck to String and then I could use .length(), am I right? Or there is another way?

```
IntStream amziusCheck = programuotojoAmzius.getText().chars();
```

Comment: `String.isEmpty()` is even better. I suggest to first use `trim` to prevent `" "` to return `false`. So `text.trim().isEmpty()`

Comment: Ahm.. You got me wrong probably. Right now my variable is int type not String, it was just a idea to make it to String

Comment: Well, you mentions `String,length` so I followed you direction. What is the type of `programuotojoAmziu` exactly ? An [mcve] would be better to give a solution based on your current situation

Comment: @AxelH this is my fx:ID. I want this 'programuotojoAmzius' use as int. By the way I want to check is this variable empty or not after launching program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the text (`programuotojoAmzius.getText()`) first, check that the text is not empty, and then process the `IntStream` if the text is not empty:

```
String value = programuotojoAmzius.getText();

if (!value.isEmpty()) {
    IntStream intStream = value.chars();
    // ...process intStream...
}
```

Note that as of JDK 11, you can also check that a `String` is blank (either empty or contains only whitespace) using the [`String::isBlank`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()):

```
String value = programuotojoAmzius.getText();

if (!value.isBlank()) {
    IntStream intStream = value.chars();
    // ...process intStream...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a `String` is empty or not, use `String.isEmpty()` it returns a `boolean`, true if it is empty, false, otherwise.